# Springboot app can not turn on in VPS

Tags: java, rest, api, spring-boot, vps

I'm writing a SprinbBoot Rest Api, currently this app working in `localhost:8080/users` and giving list of users - everything works.

But I'm trying since a lot of days to deploy this on my VPS.

So I'm uploading my `.war` file to `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps` as `ROOT.war` file.

But it doesn't work, when I go to `http://IP_MY_VPS:8080/users` I got HTTP `Status 404 - /users`.

If you want more information say it in comment.

How can be wrong ? What I should do more ? Every tip will be good.

Comment: A spring boot app can run on its own tomcat. Search how to create a spring boot Jar file. Then you only have to double click the app.

Comment: double click the app in server via SSH ? How to click it ?

Comment: It was a metaphor for the `java -jar myapp.jar`. Although, you could have windows VPS or linux + desktop VPS to double click it :)